# Suitable environment for developing a Windows application connected to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, wpf, database, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

Herro!

I'm doing some pro bono developing for our local bookshop. I am to build an application to handle their book circle

The application would have one admin view where new books, members, memberships etc. can be added/edited/deleted and one super duper simple view for the customers to either scan their ID's and scan a book to loan it or just scan an already loaned book to return it. No rocket science.

I've set up a MySQL database with appropriate tables.

Now I wonder, is WPF suitable for an application like this, or are there better/simpler alternatives? I'd prefer C#, but it's not a must. A plus would be if it's simple to make a pretty UI.

Cheers
 / Fredde!

Comment: To assess "suitable", you need to give us some criteria - otherwise, you're asking for a conversation, rather than an answer. "Better" is subjective; simpler is also quite a subjective term...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [This question is inappropriate here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/172661). This is not the place to come to ask people to recommend products, services, IDEs, programming languages, or libraries. You'll need to research that yourself. When you have specific questions about something, we'll be glad to try and answer them. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Thank you guys, and you are right, I think I was looking for more of a discussion! I apologize for my bad choosing of forum! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with what you're familiar with, and use C#. From the few details that you have given us, it sounds like it is capable of doing what you want.

Microsoft Visual C# Express would be an ideal IDE for you to use, and allows you to quickly prototype up a user interface by using drag-and-drop to position components where you need them.

Visual C# Express: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

Answer (score 0):

I think what-ever stack you feel most comfortable developing in.  C# and WPF can certainly be used to make this application, as well as any number of other development stacks.  I don't think there really is a right or wrong answer for this, just use what your comfortable with.